# Returning Min Value found in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object of keys that contain an array with objects. In each array of objects, there is a price value. I am looking to return the lowest/minimum price found. In this example, I would like to return the value **8**. Should I use reduce method?

**Object Example**

```
const obj =
{
   small: [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }],
   medium: [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }],
   large: [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
}
```

**Current Code**

```
Object.entries(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```js
const obj =
{
   small: [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }],
   medium: [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }],
   large: [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
}

const list = Object.values(obj).flat().map(val => val.price);
console.log(Math.min(...list));
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses `reduce()` to iteerate all the prices and take the min price of all of them. If it finds a price lower than the current lowest price, it replaces the `acc` value that saves the lowest price. The initial lowest price is the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

```js
const obj =
{
   small: [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }],
   medium: [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }],
   large: [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
}

const min = Object.values(obj).flat().reduce((acc, item) => 
  item.price < acc ? item.price : acc, 
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```js
const obj = {
   small: [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }],
   medium: [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }],
   large: [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
}

const values = Object.values(obj) // [[{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }], [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }], [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]]
const flated = values.flat() // [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }, { price: 33 }, { price: 8 }, { price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
const prices = flated.map(x=>x.price) // [10, 90, 33, 8, 34, 44]
const min = Math.min(...prices) // 8
```

Or use this equivalent chain:

```js
Math.min(...Object.values(obj).flat().map(o=>o.price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this chain:

```js
const obj =
{
   small: [{ price: 10 }, { price: 90 }],
   medium: [{ price: 33 }, { price: 8 }],
   large: [{ price: 34 }, { price: 44 }]
}

console.log(Math.min(...Object.values(obj).flat().map(({price}) => price)));
```

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) 
[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) 
[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)